# How to use NSIS Internet plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, nsis

I have some code that defines a variable like so:

```
....
Var IP
...
```

I have some other code that runs on init

```
Function .onInit
  ;Default installation folder
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "C:\PTL\${Project}"
  Internet::GetLocalHostIP ${IP}
FunctionEnd
```

When I run the interpreter against the script, I get a warning:

```
 [exec]   Variable "IP" not referenced or never set, wasting memory!
```

I figure this is because im not assigning some constant value to IP, and it doesnt recognize the set operation thats happening with the Internet plugin, but when I run the installer it generates, and check the JVM args which use this value (-Djava.rmi.hostname) I have this value:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=
```

I tried using a value like $8 but it does the same thing, only the value becomes:

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0

How do I use this plugin correctly?

In terms of setup, I just dropped the plugin into ./Plugins/x86-ansi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${x}` is for `!define`'s, the syntax for variables is `$x` so in your case `$IP` but the NSIS plugin API does not allow output into a variable like that.

This plugin has a unusual design, if you take a look at its included .nsh file you see it has some defines where VAR_0 = 0 etc.

This means you have to do something like this:

```
Internet::GetLocalHostIP 1 ; Tells the plugin to put the result in $1
StrCpy $IP $1 ; Copy into your variable
```